# Python script taking too much time and memory to execute

Tags: python, memory

I have a python script which uses quite a few libraries.

```
import time
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb as mysql
import cv2
import sys
import rpy2.robjects as robj
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
R = robj.r
DTW = importr('dtw')
```

Am using the below line of codes to check the memory usage(I took it up from SO only. Can't find the link right now. It gives the usage in MB).

```
process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)
```

Also, am using m3.large plan on Amazon. Attacing an image for the specification part.

[image]

**Now the question:**

The standard execution takes around 8-9 seconds. But when am executing it parallely for around 7-8 time, it's execution time shoots up to 55-60 seconds. When am trying to run it parallely for more than 10 users, time taken goes up to 120 seconds.

I tried checking the memory consumption, for a single run it takes upto 70MB for loading the libraries, then the function in the script takes 90MB.(Am also not sure that to calculate the memory consumption for the function, shall I deduct the two data i.e 90-70=20MB)

Anyways,when am running it parallely, the memory consumption increases to ~200MB for the function part. For the ditto same parameters.

Later I tried to execute the same function twice and thrice in the same script i.e called the main function 3 times in the same script, now the memory consumption is 80MB till the point libraries are imported, then for the 1st time, the memory concumption for the function is 80MB, 2nd time it is 550MB and for the third time it's 700MB. (This is totally weird for me).

As far as I understand it, the core fundamental of parallel computing is only not being followed here.

Can anyone please share some light on this.

How do I reduce the memory consumption of the script.( Am calling it via php file. It's one of the api call).

Why does the import statement consumes that much memory each time.
How do I keep the execution time to 8-9 second for each call for whatever number of times it's executing parallely.

**EDIT**

Adding the sample code:

```
import psutil
import os
import time
start_time = time.time()
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb as mysql
import cv2
import sys
import rpy2.robjects as robj
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
R = robj.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print " Memory Consumed after libraries load: "
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)

st_pt=4
# Generate our data (numpy arrays)
template = np.array([range(700),range(700),range(700)]).transpose()
query = np.array([range(10000),range(10000),range(10000)]).transpose()

# dtw algo as a function
def dtw(template,query):
    alignment = R.dtw(R.matrix(template,nrow=template.shape[0],ncol=template.shape[1]),R.matrix(query,nrow=query.shape[0],ncol=query.shape[1]),keep=True, step_pattern=R.rabinerJuangStepPattern(st_pt,"c"), open_begin=True, open_end=True)
    dist = alignment.rx('distance')[0]
    return dist


#running dtw function with parameters = template, query and calculating memory consumtion
#run 1
dtw(template,query)
process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print " Memory Consumed at dtw1: "
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)
#run 2
dtw(template,query)
process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print " Memory Consumed at dtw2: "
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)
#run 3
dtw(template,query)
process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print " Memory Consumed at dtw3: "
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)

#time taken
print(" --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output for 1st run is :

Memory Consumed after libraries load: 74.234375

Memory Consumed at dtw1: 350.53125

Memory Consumed at dtw2: 377.3125

Memory Consumed at dtw3: 537.9140625 --- 8.82202100754 seconds ---

And when I run it parallel for 5 times, the output is as follows:

Memory Consumed after libraries load: 74.87109375

Memory Consumed at dtw1: 351.16796875

Memory Consumed at dtw2: 377.94921875

Memory Consumed at dtw3: 538.55078125 --- 25.3154160976 seconds ---

Comment: I have gone through the other SO questions. Nothing helped me, that's why posted a new question.

Comment: What is the actual code?

Comment: I can't really share the whole code but am using DTW library to match a pattern in a very wide range. around 90% of the total time goes in that function(i.e 90% of 8-9 seconds.)

Comment: “I can't really share the whole code” then try to replicate the issue with a simpler code you can post. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I'll share it some time.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz,Added the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You showed only imports, not app or particular function, so my help is lot limited.

1. As I understand, you are embedding R language to python (the rpy2 lib). You are probably working with videos (cv2 lib). There could be lot of another libs python needs to load to memory because of that. You are simply using lot of libs. Try to make your code as simple as possible.
2. I think you've stumbled upon Python's GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) when you tried to execute script in parallel. But it's my guess, I really can't know from your sample what your app is really doing.

Comment: Mainly am working with the DTW library. No videos. For obvious reason, I can't really share the whole code,sorry for that. 
The main purpose of the function is to match a pattern in a very wide area. And am pretty sure that no other libraries are being called other than the mentioned ones.. And as I said in first point, for a single run, it takes nominal amount of resources. For the 2nd point of yours, am not really getting that. Can you please explain?

Comment: Better explained here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock look for third paragraph, which directly concerns numpy.